# Is it possible for an extension method to be inlined in C#?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a simple, fairly common extension method for `string.IsNullOrEmpty`:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "string!";
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
        
        Console.WriteLine(str.IsNullOrEmpty());
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] this string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
```

According to ReSharper, the IL in Release config (Any CPU) for these methods is:

```cs
main:
  .method public hidebysig static void
    Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8

    // [8 9 - 8 29]
    IL_0000: ldstr        "string!"

    // [10 9 - 10 54]
    IL_0005: dup
    IL_0006: call         bool [System.Runtime]System.String::IsNullOrEmpty(string)
    IL_000b: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)

    // [12 9 - 12 48]
    IL_0010: call         bool StringExtensions::IsNullOrEmpty(string)
    IL_0015: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)

    // [13 5 - 13 6]
    IL_001a: ret

  } // end of method Program::Main

IsNullOrEmpty:
  .method public hidebysig static bool
    IsNullOrEmpty(
      string 'value'
    ) cil managed
  {
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(unsigned int8)
      = (01 00 02 00 00 ) // .....
      // unsigned int8(2) // 0x02
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute::.ctor()
      = (01 00 00 00 )
    .param [1]
      .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhenAttribute::.ctor(bool)
        = (01 00 00 00 00 ) // .....
        // bool(false)
    .maxstack 8

    // [20 9 - 20 44]
    IL_0000: ldarg.0      // 'value'
    IL_0001: call         bool [System.Runtime]System.String::IsNullOrEmpty(string)
    IL_0006: ret

  } // end of method StringExtensions::IsNullOrEmpty
```

Adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` or any other seemingly appropriate `MethodImplOptions` has no effect. Removing `[NotNullWhen(false)]`has no effect.

This method is simple enough that I'd have assumed the compiler would just replace the call on `bool StringExtensions::IsNullOrEmpty(string)` with the `bool [System.Runtime]System.String::IsNullOrEmpty(string)`.

Is there nothing to be gained by replacing it? Sure, it's just adding a before the call to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, but it's a relatively trivial substitution, right?

Comment: Inlining happens at JIT time. I.e. during IL to machine code translation. You won't find any evidence of inlining when inspecting the IL because it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: `var a = new Func<string, bool>((/* this */x) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));` doesn't really work. So probably not...

Comment: The C# compiler never inlines anything compiling to IL; it's important that distinct methods remain distinct methods in order to make things like reflection and IL patching work OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are just "syntactic sugar".

From the jitters point of view there is no difference between an extension method call and any other method call. But the inlining will be done by the jitter, so you need to inspect the actual assembly code from the jitter, not the IL code produced by the compiler.

The rules for what may be inlined or not may also vary between jitter versions, so you may need to inspect the output for each jitter version you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise it happened later.